# Copy Range based on specific worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I know enough macros/VBA to be dangerous, and have taken on a task that is definitely more than I can handle.  My client workbook has multiple billing sheets, each with a unique sheet title based on what the billing is.  At any point in time, I may need to copy the specific range that has the premiums from any billing sheet to my summary sheet.

- I have added a button to my summary sheet to run code in order to copy the specific (fixed) range from whichever billing sheet I ask for

I know the code to create an InputBox (so I can tell excel which sheet to go to) but where I am failing is having excel respond to the InputBox by saying "OK... I will go to the sheet with the name you typed in and copy cells A1:A20... and paste them into the current sheet starting in cell C1".  I have tried multiple iterations and they either do nothing or error out.  Current iteration is below... but keeps erroring out...

```
Public Sub MacroPremiumCopy()
  Dim ShtName As String

  ShtName = InputBox("Enter the name for the copied worksheet")

  If ShtName <> "" Then
    Worksheets("ShtName").Range("X7:X98").Copy _
    Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("M14").Paste
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to replace `Worksheets("ShtName")` with `Worksheets(ShtName)`, otherwise you are always referring to a worksheet that is literally called "ShtName" instead of a worksheet that has a name as contained within the `Shtname` variable. Secondly if you're using the `Destination` parameter of the `Copy` method, then you should not add `.Paste` at the end of the destination cell range.

Corrected code:

```
Public Sub MacroPremiumCopy()
  Dim ShtName As String

  ShtName = InputBox("Enter the name for the copied worksheet")
 
  If ShtName <> "" Then
    Sheets(ShtName).Range("X7:X98").Copy _
    Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("M14")
  End If
End Sub
```

### Edit

If you want the formatting of the destination cells to be preserved (i.e. copy values only), use the following code:

```
Public Sub MacroPremiumCopy()
  Dim ShtName As String

  ShtName = InputBox("Enter the name for the copied worksheet")
 
  If ShtName <> "" Then
    Sheets(ShtName).Range("X7:X98").Copy
    ActiveSheet.Range("M14").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Xukrao, you are my absolutely hero!  Can I bother you for one last thing... is there something I can tag onto the end of the code so that destination formatting sticks.  I googled a solution but it errored out.

Comment: @GeorgeKustos See the edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Values From a Range in a Worksheet to Another Worksheet

```vb
Sub CopyPremiums()
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Copy Premiums"
    
    ' Store the worksheet name retrieved from the user, in a variable.
    Dim swsName As String
    swsName = InputBox("Enter the worksheet name", PROC_TITLE)
    
    ' Exit when canceled by the user or nothing was entered.
    If swsName = "" Then Exit Sub
   
    ' Attempt to reference the source worksheet, the one to be copied from.
    Dim sws As Worksheet:
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent error if it doesn't exist
        Set sws = dws.Parent.Worksheets(swsName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Exit when the attempt was unsuccessful i.e. the sheet doesn't exist.
    If sws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The worksheet """ & swsName & """ doesn't exist!", _
            vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Reference the destination worksheet, the one containing the button,
    ' the one being written to.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = ActiveSheet
    ' Note that using 'ActiveSheet' is rather risky here, especially since it
    ' is being written to because the active sheet might be the wrong one
    ' when the code is not run from the button on it.
    ' A safe way would be to fully qualify the worksheet with e.g.:
    'Set dws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Premiums Summary")

    ' Copy values only i.e. preserve the destination formatting.
    ' This is the most efficient way and doesn't mess up the selection.
    With sws.Range("X7:X98")
        dws.Range("M14").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    End With
    
    ' Inform, so the user knows the code has run (successfully).
    MsgBox "Premiums copied from worksheet """ & swsName & """.", _
        vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

End Sub
```